# issue when trying to populate database with @PostConstruct

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to populate a freshly created database schema via Spring and Hibernate.

My `@PostConstruct` class is:

```
@Component
public class DataInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void firstLoad() {
        if (!(userProfileService.findAll().size() > 0)) {
            System.out.println("persistUserProfiles()");
            persistUserProfiles();
        } else {
            System.out.println("persistUserProfiles() NOT EXECUTED!");
        }   

        if (userService.findAll().size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("loadDefaultUser()");
            loadDefaultUser();
        } else {
            System.out.println("loadDefaultUser() NOT EXECUTED!");
        }
    }

    private void loadDefaultUser() {
        User user = new User();

        user.setSsoId("master");
        user.setPassword("$2a$10$Jv/rZ8wa7XiRY8XZ1lpIMeXL/Mol0Eda4XxHM7BE2Ui6BxpLZ95He");
        user.setFirstName("HRM");
        user.setLastName("Master User");
        user.setEmail("email@email");
        user.setState(State.ACTIVE.getState());
        user.setUserProfiles(loadDefaultUserProfiles());

        userService.save(user);
    }

    private Set<UserProfile> loadDefaultUserProfiles() {
        Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
        userProfiles.add(userProfileService.findByType(UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType()));
        userProfiles.add(userProfileService.findByType(UserProfileType.ADMIN.getUserProfileType()));
        userProfiles.add(userProfileService.findByType(UserProfileType.DBA.getUserProfileType()));

        return userProfiles;
    }

    private void persistUserProfiles() {
        UserProfile user = new    UserProfile(UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType());
        userProfileService.save(user);

        UserProfile admin = new UserProfile(UserProfileType.ADMIN.getUserProfileType());
        userProfileService.save(admin);

        UserProfile dba = new     UserProfile(UserProfileType.DBA.getUserProfileType());
    userProfileService.save(dba);
    }
}
```

But when running the application server, I'm getting the following console output and error:

```
persistUserProfiles()
loadDefaultUser()
Mar 06, 2016 5:15:25 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext __refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: b.c.m.h.m.UserProfile
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5075)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The output clearly states the problem is on the `UserProfile` entity, which is defined as:

```
@Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

// Constructor used only for initial data loading, not used after
public UserProfile() {
}

// Constructor used only for initial data loading, not used after
public UserProfile(String type) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

The enum for defining `UserProfileType` is:

```
USER("USER"),
DBA("DBA"),
ADMIN("ADMIN");

String userProfileType;

private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
    this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
}

public String getUserProfileType(){
    return userProfileType;
}
```

**EDIT: include of (hopefully) relevant code**

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public void save(User user){
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        dao.save(user);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        // user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        dao.saveOrUpdate(user);
    (...)
}
```

PasswordEncoder is `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`.

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<String, User> implements UserDao {

    public void save(User user) {
        persist(user);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        saveOrUpdate(user);
    }
    (...)
}
```

And the abstract class that handles the sessions:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
    (...)
}
```

What's happening? All tables are being created, and user_profile table gets populated, but the `DataInitializer` class fails on assigning user profiles to the "master" user who does not gets persisted.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `userService.saveOrUpdate` instead of `userService.save`. That should work, if it does, then I will add explanation as answer.

Comment: @Mubin, userService is an interface and I had to implement the `saveOrUpdate` method on the DAO layer, no worries there. But, when I tried to run, there was an `java.lang.StackOverflowError` something related to the password. Commenting out the password line, I still get this same error.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of userService too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<String, User> implements UserDao {

public void save(User user) {
    persist(user);
}

public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
    saveOrUpdate(user);
}
(...)
```

}

The problem was that from inside the method `saveOrUpdate(User user)` I referencing itself.

The solution was:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
    super.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```